# Login system send_mail function?

Tags: php, email, authentication

i installed a very nice login system from this website: http://tutorialzine.com/2009/10/cool-login-system-php-jquery/

im not experienced in php. I have a question that people in the comments asked too

When a new user registers, the email is send from: demo-test@tutorialzine.com
How do i change it so it would be send using my own email address. I have tried changing it in the sendmail but it doesn't work

---

**edit:

ok i found out the problem is that when i use the email of my own domain, php doesn't support smtp or something so i have to use phpmailer
i have installed phpmailer, can somebody please fix my code so it would use phpmailer**

**Functions.php**

```
<?php

if(!defined('INCLUDE_CHECK')) die('You are not allowed to execute this file directly');

function checkEmail($str)
{
    return preg_match("/^[\.A-z0-9_\-\+]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z]{1,4}$/", $str);
}


function send_mail($from,$to,$subject,$body)
{
    $headers = '';
    $headers .= "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-to: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $from\n";
    $headers .= "Message-ID: <" . md5(uniqid(time())) . "@" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ">\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Date: " . date('r', time()) . "\n";

    mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
}
?>
```

**DownloadLinks.php (partial)**

```
<?php

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

require 'connect.php';
require 'functions.php';
// Those two files can be included only if INCLUDE_CHECK is defined


session_name('tzLogin');
// Starting the session

session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
// Making the cookie live for 2 weeks

session_start();

if($_SESSION['id'] && !isset($_COOKIE['tzRemember']) && !$_SESSION['rememberMe'])
{
    // If you are logged in, but you don't have the tzRemember cookie (browser restart)
    // and you have not checked the rememberMe checkbox:

    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    // Destroy the session
}


if(isset($_GET['logoff']))
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    header("Location: DownloadLinks.php");
    exit;
}

if($_POST['submit']=='Login')
{
    // Checking whether the Login form has been submitted

    $err = array();
    // Will hold our errors


    if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
        $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

    if(!count($err))
    {
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

        // Escaping all input data

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr FROM tz_members WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));

        if($row['usr'])
        {
            // If everything is OK login

            $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

            // Store some data in the session

            setcookie('tzRemember',$_POST['rememberMe']);
        }
        else $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
    }

    if($err)
    $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    // Save the error messages in the session

    header("Location: DownloadLinks.php");
    exit;
}
else if($_POST['submit']=='Register')
{
    // If the Register form has been submitted

    $err = array();

    if(strlen($_POST['username'])<4 || strlen($_POST['username'])>32)
    {
        $err[]='Your username must be between 3 and 32 characters!';
    }

    if(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9\-\_\.]+/i',$_POST['username']))
    {
        $err[]='Your username contains invalid characters!';
    }

    if(!checkEmail($_POST['email']))
    {
        $err[]='Your email is not valid!';
    }

    if(!count($err))
    {
        // If there are no errors

        $pass = substr(md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].microtime().rand(1,100000)),0,6);
        // Generate a random password

        $_POST['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        // Escape the input data


        mysql_query("   INSERT INTO tz_members(usr,pass,email,regIP,dt)
                        VALUES(

                            '".$_POST['username']."',
                            '".md5($pass)."',
                            '".$_POST['email']."',
                            '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',
                            NOW()

                        )");

        if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1)
        {
            send_mail(  'demo-test@tutorialzine.com',
                        $_POST['email'],
                        'Registration System - Your New Password',
                        'Your password is: '.$pass);

            $_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']='We sent you an email with your new password!';
        }
        else $err[]='This username is already taken!';
    }

    if(count($err))
    {
        $_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    }   

    header("Location: DownloadLinks.php");
    exit;
}

$script = '';

if($_SESSION['msg'])
{
    // The script below shows the sliding panel on page load

    $script = '
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){

            $("div#panel").show();
            $("#toggle a").toggle();
        });

    </script>';

}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by searching online.

installed  [PEAR Mail package](http://email.about.com/gi/o.htm?zi=1/XJ&zTi=1&sdn=email&cdn=compute&tm=76&f=21&tt=13&bt=0&bts=0&zu=http%3A//pear.php.net/package/Mail)

then changed everything like this

```
if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1)
{

require_once "Mail.php";

 $from = "Name <mail@example.com>";
 $to = $_POST['email'];
 $subject = "Registration System- Your New Password";


 $body = "Thank you for registering\n Your password is: .$pass \n Please login with your registered email and password";

 $host = "mail.example.com";
 $username = "admin@example.com";
 $password = "password";

 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
   'To' => $to,
   'Subject' => $subject);
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

        if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
   $_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']='We sent you an email with your new password! Check your junk/spam too!';}

        }

        else $err[]='This username is already taken!';
    }
```

Comment: source: http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
send_mail(  'demo-test@tutorialzine.com',
                        $_POST['email'],
                        'Registration System - Your New Password',
                        'Your password is: '.$pass);
```

in DownloadLinks.php

the 1st parameter is the From email address(demo-test@tutorialzine.com), you can change it to your own